# Limitation of Decimal places of String datatype from database to HTML page

Tags: java, html, string, apache-stringutils, string-utils

I'm getting the **String type decimal number** from the local database.

And

I viewed three decimal places in my UI application(html page).so now i need to limit it as 2 deciaml places.

**Example** `String Amount = "123.786";`

change the amount decimal value  to "123.78"(to be displayed in my web application)

Please help to limit it to two decimal places.

I tried using Stringutils functionality but i can't absorb it.

Comment: The DecimalFormat class has methods for specifying the number of digits in a String displaying a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 String Amount = "123.786";
 String value= String.format("%.2f", Float.valueOf(Amount));

or 

BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(Amount).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

Comment: it worked!thanks!! please say how to limit the Timestamp value upto seconds.is there any function to cut off milliseconds from timestamp

Comment: Happy to hear it.. Please define your question briefly and post another question with input and expected output..All we are waiting helping to you.......